# JavaScript execution order in an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

If I have an HTML page embedding several `<script>` tags, is there a guarantee that these script files will be executed in order they appear in the HTML file?

For example:

```
<script src="script1"></script>
<script src="script2"></script>
```

Is it guaranteed that `script1` will always be executed before `script2`? If so, is it a cross-browser standard?

Comment: They will be parsed and interpreted in the order you have included them..

Comment: `Is it guaranteed that script1 will always be executed before script2?` YES,  the script are loaded synchronously. That means they execute one after the other.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have a ajax call in the first one, the second script will not wait for the call to be done

Comment: In supporting browsers you may set the [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async) attribute. It defaults to false => synchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. The browser will download both scripts in parallel and execute them as soon as possible, maintaining their order. Here's a [handfull article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/) that treats this subject.

Comment: Nice. BTW I found the standard here if it's helpful to other people:  https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async

Answer (score 0):

Those JS files will be **parsed and interpreted** by browser in the order you putted them : script1.js, then script2.js.

*However, it doesn't garanty that the code in `script1.js` will be **executed** before `script2.js` : it depends on the code.*

For example, let's consider you are listening to a DOM ready event in `script2.js` and you are listening to an image loaded event in `script1.js`. In this case, **the code in `script2.js` will be parsed and interpreted after the code in `script1.js`, but it will be executed after**.